# Manga about a kid who's transported to a different world by going under his bed and counting to ten

Tags: story-identification

It was about a kid who went under his bed counted to 10 and was transported to a different world.

I remember he fell into a river and got permanent tear marks on his face.

To add to this question, his stuffed animal came to life and the world he came into was populated by anthropomorphic animals. Sugar was a type of drug and they also had access to magic through crystals. It was in English before 2016 but not before the 2005. The main character was a blonde child and one of his parents had died, if I recall correctly.

Comment: This is a story-identification question about a manga that involves a character who has been "transported to a different world", which sounds fantastical. Hence, I have migrated it here.

Comment: If you can go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and fill in as many details as you can, we'd be much obliged. It will help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

The manga you're looking for is very likely Undertown! I'd finally hunted it down myself by remembering it was published in the states by Tokyopop!

To add details, the kid, named Sama, is stressed after he believes his father is dying of an uncurable heart condition. At the hospital, he meets a strange man that tells him of the titiular world of Undertown and how to get there: Crawling under your bed and counting to ten.

He falls into the world of Undertown after doing this, somehow ending up with permanent tear streaks down his cheeks. His teddy bear comes to life in order to protect him in a world where bees and anthropomorphic animals are at war over a magical crystal called the Sugar Stone.

Comment: Can you add some details to show how this is what OP is looking for?